# Conditional Count/Sum in Select

Tags: mysql

I've been trying differnt ways of approaching this, but I'm not having to much luck.

Basically this query returns all the directories an employee is built into.  I need to add a field to the select of this query that lists how many other users with 'admin' access (u.access_level) are built into the directory).

```
Table:  Directories (has many users)
Table:  Users (users of the directory with different access levels)

SELECT d.id, d.name, u.employee_number, u.access_level, u.id 'user_id', 
(** count of all users of this directory where their u.access_level = 'admin) AS admins 
FROM directories d JOIN users u ON d.id = u.directory_id 
WHERE u.employee_number = '045283' 
ORDER BY d.NAME
```

So, I need to return a recordset of all directories an employee is built into, including the total number of users that have 'admin' access to each directory.    Basically I need a count for some later framework logic like 'if the employee is the last admin of this directory - don't allow them to delete themselves or change their access level - upgrade another user to admin level first).

It feels like I'm needing a sub-query, but that's a little beyond my SQL skills right now.   Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select d.id, d.name, u.employee_number, u.access_level, u.id 'user_id'
    , (Select Count(*)
        From directories As D1
            Join users As U1
                On U1.directory_id = D1.id
        Where U1.access_level = 'admin'
            And D1.id = D.id) As AdminUsers
From directories As D
    Join users As U
        On U.directory_id = D.id
Where u.employee_number = '045283'
Order By d.Name
```

Another solution using a derived table (which might perform better):

```
Select d.id, d.name, u.employee_number, u.access_level, u.id 'user_id'
    , Coalesce(AdminDir.AdminCount,0) As AdminCount
From directories As D
    Join users As U
        On U.directory_id = D.id
    Left Join   (
                Select D1.id, Count(*) As AdminCount
                From directories As D1
                    Join users As U1
                        On U1.directory_id = D1.id
                Where U1.access_level = 'admin'
                Group By D1.id  
                ) As AdminDir
            On AdminDir.id = D.id
Where u.employee_number = '045283'
Order By d.Name
```

Comment: Awesome THANK YOU! - I only tried the 2nd example - it works perfectly (way past my current skill level).  One minor type-o is on the 2nd line: 'AdminDir.AdminAcount' should be 'AdminDir.AdminCount.

Comment: @Reno - Glad I could help. I'll fix the typo you mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

```
sum(if(u.access_level = 'admin',1,0)) as admins
```

edit. Please note that this condition can be rewritten even in this way

```
sum(u.access_level = 'admin')
```

because mysql simply returns 1 if condition is true or 0 if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, u.employee_number, u.access_level, u.id 'user_id', 
SUM(IF(u.access_level = 'admin',1,0)) AS admins 
FROM directories d JOIN users u ON d.id = u.directory_id 
WHERE u.employee_number = '045283' 
ORDER BY d.NAME
```

this way the field will only add 1 when the `u.access_level = 'admin'` and if it's not then it will add 0 - which of course means it will not count it

Comment: That was close to one of my failed attempts actually.   Doing it that way only a single row is returned listing the first found directory with a total count of owners in all directories.  Thank you though!

Comment: @Reno : well it's quite simple then - simply group by the `d.id` field wich will show a single result per directory

Answer (score 1):

Would you be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, u.employee_number, u.access_level, u.id 'user_id', 
SUM(IF(u.access_level = 'admin',1,0)) AS admins
FROM directories d JOIN users u ON d.id = u.directory_id 
WHERE u.employee_number = '045283' 
ORDER BY d.NAME
```

Comment: Same problem as with BigFatBaby's example:  Doing it that way only returns the first directory an employee has access to with a total count of admins in all the directories they have access to.  Thank you though!