# How to include user in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I currently have a query that returns a list of every post that exists, its comments (concatenated), and how many likes it has.

I would like to include a column that that indicates whether or not the user has upvoted/liked this specific post. The structure of the relevant tables are as follows:

likes (id, elementID, googleID)
elements (id, googleID, time, title, body, type)
comments (id, elementID, googleID, body)

So how would I go through the likes, determine if one of them has the user's ID (dynamically put into the query via Node.JS), and then create a column indicating a simple true or false?

```
SELECT E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type, C.comments, E.googleID, L.likeCount
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
```

Comment: Some sample data will help. Try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer much faster. That query works and you want help to update that? or you want create a new query ? googleID is the user?

Comment: googleID is the user. I'd like to add to this query to add another column that indicates whether or not the user has liked the post (which is an element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `LEFT JOIN` against `likes`, passing the user's `googleID` into the join's `ON` clause. If values from that join are non-null, then the user has liked the post. If null, the user has not liked it.

Note that your first subquery join is unnecessary. That can be taken care of directly in the `SELECT` list, and by adding all the other selected columns to the `GROUP BY` clause (actually that isn't even necessary in MySQL owing to its default behavior of group by lenience, but is a good habit to be in since other RDBMS require it)

```
SELECT
  E.id,
  E.time,
  E.title,
  E.body,
  E.type,
  -- This can be moved to the outer SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(C.body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments,
  E.googleID,
  L.likeCount,
  -- Conditional statement to match non-nulls in the
  -- left joined likes table, indicating whether the
  -- user has liked the post
  CASE
    -- has a like, return true
    WHEN Luser.id IS NOT NULL THEN true
    -- does not have a like, return false
    ELSE false
  END AS userLiked
FROM elements E
-- Convert this to a plain left join instead of subquery
LEFT JOIN comments C ON C.elementID = E.id
-- Left join against likes, strictly matching the user id
LEFT JOIN likes Luser
  ON Luser.elementID = E.id
  -- Pass the user id into the join condition.
  AND Luser.googleID = <the user's id>
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
-- Put the other columns into GROUP BY
-- instead of another left join subquery
GROUP BY
  E.id,
  -- MySQL will let you get by without the rest of these
  -- but it is good practice to use them. Other RDBMS would
  -- not allow them to be omitted...
  E.time,
  E.title,
  E.body,
  E.type,
  E.googleID
  likeCount,
  userLiked
```

If you prefer to go back to using your subquery join for the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, you may revert to that and remove the outer `GROUP BY`, but it may not be as fast as this method.

Comment: It says column body in field list is ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, because of the comment body. Add a `C` alias.  `GROUP_CONCAT(C.body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments,`

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional `SUM` this will be `0` or something `>0` in case user like it.

```
SELECT 
     E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type, 
     C.comments, E.googleID, L.likeCount, L.user_likeit
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT elementID, COUNT(id) AS likeCount, SUM( CASE 
                                                     WHEN googleID =@userID THEN 1
                                                     ELSE 0
                                                   END
                                                 ) as user_likeit
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY elementID
) L ON L.elementID = E.id;
```

I google and found [*Conditional Count/Sum in Select*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342228/conditional-count-sum-in-select) and looks like can also work

```
sum(googleID = @userID)
```